# Slack bot responds to slash commands only in first channel

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-commands

I have created a bot with a slash command that works, but it only responds to the channel in which the first Incoming Webhook was created. I would like it to respond in whatever channel (public or private) in which it was invoked.

I've tried creating a webhook for each channel and reinstalling the bot in my workspace, but it still reverts to the first channel.

I can see how I could hard code a webhook -> channel mapping in my code (php on my webserver) but that seems like a lot of very specific coding, and how would I ever release the bot to another workspace? I'm sure I'm missing something basic, but I can't work it out.

How do I deploy my bot so that it will respond to a slash command in whichever public or private channel it was invoked?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it. The example I was following had the webhook URL hard coded in the script. I just realised, upon re-reading the docs, that the actual webhook is passed in the POST data as response_url. Now it's all working fine. RTFM next time